# Print HTML poster format as PDF

Tags: windows-7, pdf, printing

I´ve created a scientific poster using HTML and CSS. The dimensions are 90cm x 120cm.

The result is great, but I´m having some difficulties printing this poster as PDF.

I´m trying to print two PDF versions:

1. Original poster format (90x120cm) on a single PDF sheet
2. A scaled down A4 version to hand out

How can I print these versions?

(I´m on w Win 7 machine. Haven´t installed any PDF plugins yet. The Chrome/IE default PDF printing programs only allow me to print the poster over multiple sheets as far as I know.)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the application [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), an amazing little app that allows you to edit and print PDFs from the command line.

Among the many parameters you can use, are the height and the width of the PDF file. In my case I used the following command:

```
wkhtmltopdf --zoom 1.2 --page-height 1200mm --page-width 900mm file:///C:/path/to/myfile.html myfile.pdf
```